# Explanation of proof of transcendence of $e$

Tags: proof-explanation, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory, eulers-number-e

I'm following the proof for the transcendence of $e$ from the book "Transcendental Numbers" by M. Ram Murty and Purusottam Rath. I am struggling to understand the final few lines.
[image: Proof of transcendence of e part 1]
[image: Proof of transcendence of e part 2]

As far as I understand, by the triangle inequality we have

$$
|J|\leq \sum_{k=0}^n |a_k| |I(k,f)|.
$$
Now $I(0,f)=0$, so the sum starts from $k=1$. So then

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k| |I(k,f)|\leq nA\max_{1\leq k\leq n}|I(k,f)| \leq nA\max_{1\leq k\leq n}\{ke^kF(k)\} = n^2Ae^n\max_{1\leq k\leq n}F(k)
$$
where $A:=\max\limits_{1\leq k\leq n}|a_k|$.

This is where I'm stumped because I don't know how to bound $F(k)$. I've read some other proofs for help, but they all slightly differ at this step.

Also, where does the "elementary" observation that $e^p\geq p^{p-1}/(p-1)!$ come from? And why is this needed? Can't we just say that the factorial function grows faster than the exponential function so that eventually the inequality $(p-1)!\leq (2n)!^p$ would be false?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain the notations? I don't have the book.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to attach the images. I've edited the post now.

Comment: This doesn't explain what is $I(k,f)$. I can suppose $f$ is the hypothetical polynomial which has $\mathrm e$ as a  root.

Comment: $I(t,f)$ is defined 3 lines above (2.1) and $f$ is a polynomial defined just after $J$

Comment: Oh! Right. I forgot to look at the first page screenshot. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As regards the bound on $F$, we have that
   $$F(x)=x^{p-1}(x+1)^p\cdots(x+n)^p$$
   and therefore, for $k=1,\dots,n$,
   $$F(k)k=k^{p}(k+1)^p\cdots(k+n)^p\leq ((2n)!)^p.$$
   Hence
   $$\sum_{k=0}^n|a_k|e^kF(k)k\leq Ae^n\sum_{k=1}^nF(k)k\leq Ae^n\sum_{k=1}^n((2n)!)^p=Ane^n((2n)!)^p.$$
2. Note that
   $$e^p=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^k}{k!}>\sum_{k=0}^{p-1}\frac{p^k}{k!}=1+p+\frac{p^2}{2!}+\dots +\frac{p^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}>\frac{p^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}.$$
   The contradiction follows from the fact that
   $$p^{p-1}e^{-p}\leq Ane^n((2n)!)^p$$
   does not eventually hold. Indeed, when $p$ is large enough, the LHS becomes greater than the RHS because
   $$\lim_{p\to +\infty}\frac{p^{p-1}}{Ane^{p+n}((2n)!)^p}=+\infty.$$
   You are right, it is not needed and your argument works as well.

Comment: Ah I understand now, thank you. But I still don't understand how to obtain the $\frac{((2n)!)^p}{n}$ bound on $F$.

Comment: @AviMukesh Please see my edit.